# VBA filter on pivot table field for specific word in a string

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, filtering

I have an excel "DB" with employees and their car reg numbers (up to 3 reg numbers per person).

I wrote a vba script that filters a pivot table and returns the employee name/surname, type of parking permit they have. I did not know how to filter the non-pivot table using vba to check in each of the 3 columns that hold the 3 different reg numbers so I created a concatenated field of the 3 reg and built a pivot using on that main table.

The vba code I have is working but it's taking quite a bit of time to go through the pivot items.

Can anyone suggest a faster way of filtering either the 3 columns for one reg number (don't know in which column this is) or the concatenated field?

```
'This code works but takes a considerable amount to filter through thousands of records. I need it to be 'fast (almost instant).

Sub FilterRegNumbers()
    Dim Criteria As String
    Dim PivotItem As PivotItem

    ' Get criteria from the "Main" sheet
    Criteria = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("F2").Value

    ' Clear existing filters in the "All Regs" PivotField
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("All Regs").ClearAllFilters

    ' Loop through PivotItems and filter based on criteria
    For Each PivotItem In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("All Regs").PivotItems
        If InStr(1, PivotItem.Name, Criteria, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            PivotItem.Visible = True
        Else
            PivotItem.Visible = False
        End If
    Next PivotItem

    ' Switch back to the "Main" sheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Select
End Sub
```

```
'This code throws an error when using the xlCaptionContains
Sub FilterRegNumbers()
    Dim Criteria As String
    
    ' Get criteria from the "Main" sheet
    Criteria = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Range("F2").Value
    
    ' Clear existing filters in the "All Regs" PivotField
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("All Regs").ClearAllFilters
 
    ' Apply custom filter to "All Regs" PivotField
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("pivot").PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("All Regs").PivotFilters.Add Type:=xlCaptionContains, Value1:=Criteria
 
    ' Switch back to the "Main" sheet
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Main").Select
End Sub
```

Data Table
[image: Data Table]
Pivot Table
[image: Pivot]
Main tab where you enter reg number and press vba button to return all details
[image: Main tab where you enter reg number and press vba button to return all details]

Comment: Try Application.ScreenUpdating=False and True

Comment: You could just have the "All Regs" field with the rest as a pivot field and then use `xlCaptionContains`, I'm yet to find a different solution than this or adding `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` (for the duration of the filtering) to what Black cat said.

Comment: Thanks both.
Notus_Panda, I did not think of having All Refs as a field! Did that and the second code I had runs under 1 sec. Thank you very much.